Error loading shared library liblibwkhtmltox : No such file or directory
I am new to docker/AKS world. In my application, PDF generation stopped working, when someone started using alpine .net 3.1 image. Prior to using alpine image, it was working fine. I have tried all the things mentioned in various forums like github etc, but no success. Can someone please help ? Also error message strangely shows "liblib" before actual dll name. Here is my partial docker file -
RUN apk add libgdiplus --repository http://dl-3.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/testing/ --allow-untrusted
RUN wget -P /app https://github.com/rdvojmoc/DinkToPdf/raw/master/v0.12.4/64%20bit/libwkhtmltox.dll
RUN wget -P /app https://github.com/rdvojmoc/DinkToPdf/raw/master/v0.12.4/64%20bit/libwkhtmltox.dylib
RUN wget -P /app https://github.com/rdvojmoc/DinkToPdf/raw/master/v0.12.4/64%20bit/libwkhtmltox.so
